# Log4j log file not generated on first run of project

Tags: java, jsp, log4j

When i am running my project for first time after server startup log4j log file is not getting generated and i am getting FileNotFoundException. But on second run of my project i am getting the logger file created and everything runs perfect. What might be the cause for this typical behaviour?

This is my log4j.properties file which is in default package.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL , stdout, File

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=\u001b[35m%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x %-5p %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log File, support File rolling.
log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.File=${logfile.name}
log4j.appender.File.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.File.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}[%t] %x %c: %-5p - %m%n
```

Here i am setting my filename with custom path using System.property

```
<%System.setProperty("logfile.name", getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "../logs");%>
<%!final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("login.jsp");%>
<%logger.info("working");%>
```

I am using log4j-1.2.15.jar, 
Netbeans 8.2 IDE, 
Tomcat 8.0 Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the missing log file is caused by the approach used to initialize the `logfile.name` property.

Log4j init sequence is executed before the JSP where `System.setProperty` is invoked, so it keeps the incorrect value corresponding to the placeholder `${logfile.name}` and such file does not exist.

When the JSP is invoked, it sets the system property to a valid file name, so it begins to run properly for further invocations.

This property should not be set through the JSP, it must be done elsewhere, preferably *not* in the code part of the application. For example, using the script that deploys the application, or basically in the `log4j.properties` itself.